# sequence classification model

Tags: machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning

I have sequence of signal data

```
[   5948    5969    6015 ... 9476439 9476527 9476617]
```

which is `91509` long. For each of above value we have label

```
['+' 'N' 'V' ... 'N' 'N' 'N']
```

Current what I am doing is I am creating the window of particular length. eg window of length `100`. So `91509` records will be divided into window of 100 size.

I give a label to each window

**Label Priority**

```
label2num={ 'A':1,'+':2, 'N':2, 'V':2, '"':2}

def PickLabel(row):
    if(label2num['A'] in row):  # If one label is A, assign it to A 
      return 'A'
    elif(label2num['V'] in row):  # If one label is V, assign it to V (No A should be present)
      return 'V'
    elif(np.all(row[row!=0] == label2num['N'])): ## If all labels are 'N'
      return "V"
    else:  # Else unclassified.
      return '~'
```

So now it is easy to create the classifier for above labeled data.

Problem - I am not getting good accuracy for above logic, where I take window of 100 size and do prediction.

Is there any algorithm or approach available, where it learns from `sequence of characters` and based on that it predicts the class name for input signal?

Priority is as per given in priority if-else section.